# JSF/Spring How to use h:selectOneMenu without SelectItem objects

Tags: java, jsf

I have a Collection of model objects in my backing bean, and I want to use the f:selectItems tag to display them in a `h:selectOneMenu`.  I have read many tutorials that recommend using a collection of SelectItem objects instead of my model POJOs.  However, I do not want to do this because it ties your model to a faces presentation.  Is there any way to achieve this?  I keep getting a Servlet Exception - `"incompatible with javax.faces.model.SelectItem."` I have posted a few sample snippets below:

Java:

```
@Component(value = "headerBean")
@Scope(value = "session")
class HeaderBean{

private Collection<ValueObject> myCollectionOfValueObjects = new ArrayList<ValueObject>();
// ...
// getter, setters, whatnot...
// ...
}
```

JSP:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectMenu" value="#{headerBean.myValueObject}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{headerBean.myCollectionOfValueObjects}"/> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use SelectItem only.

Use converter for the same , [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) is an article

Answer (score 1):

You need a `SelectItem` because this is the way JSF knows what to display and what to pass as a value.

Perhaps it would be nice if you could specify something like:

`<f:selectItems collection="#{bean.colelction}" itemKey="id" itemLabel="name" />` - but you can't in JSF 1.2. [It is available](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) in JSF 2.0, however.